# How to extract a part of a char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I receive 10 bytes (`010830FFFFFFFFFF0304`) in hexa on terminal, and I need to write only a part of this array (This 5 bytes `FFFFFFFFFF`) in another char array.

Here´s the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char buffer[];  // buffer size in bytes
    int i;          // counter
    while(true){
        for(i=0; i<buffer; i++){
            buffer[i] = getc();
        }
    }
}
```

How to extract this part of array?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why is there a while(true) around the for loop?

Comment: wehere `true` is defined??

Comment: Your question makes no sense so far.  First, `buffer` cannot be created without a size.  A value must be inside the `[]`.  i<buffer is not proper, as `i` is an `int`, and `buffer` is a `char[]`.  Work on getting your existing code to a usable point, then you can ask a question about adding on to it.

Comment: How are you trying to determine those 5 bytes?  What's the problem you're having/trying to solve?  Are you just trying to do a [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan In `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @H2CO3 ;)  Not included

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan And `void main()` is non-standard. I know, I know...

Answer (score 6):

General fixup:

- I declared an actual size for `buffer` (10), where you did not have a size.
- I declared an array for your answer (`middle`), where you did not have such a space.
- I loop 10 times, instead of the non-sense comparison `i<buffer`
- I removed the outer `while(true)`, which would never terminate.
- I [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) from the input buffer to the answer, for 5 characters.

Your question is very unclear and imprecise, so I can only guess at what you intended.

```
void main()
{
    char buffer[10]; // buffer size in bytes
    char middle[5];
    int i; // counter

    for(i=0; i<10; ++i){
        buffer[i] = getc();
    }

    memcpy(middle, &buffer[3], 5*sizeof(char));

    for(i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        printf("%x",middle[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main(){
    char buffer[64]; // buffer size in bytes
    char result[10];
    int i; // counter
    while(1){
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    buffer[i] = getc(stdin);
    }
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
       result[i] = buffer[i+3];
    }
    result[i] = 0;  // end string
    printf("%s\n",result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's 5 here?? Why the `while()`?

Comment: @Jim I bet you didn't try compiling this :P, `true` isn't native to `C` and `stdio.h` isn't valid in `C++`

Comment: Fixed. And other stuff too. 5 is 5 bytes he wants.

Answer (score 0):

as it seems you have a while(true) loop and all you need to do is just create another char array and put the needed chars in it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char buffer[10]; // buffer size in bytes
    char smallBuf[5]; // buffer size in bytes
    int i; // counter

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = getc();
    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        smallBuf[i] = buffer[i + 3];
    }
}
```